# StackExchange Podcast Logo missing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, podcast

Without a logo is looks somewhat sad, doesn't it?
[image]

Comment: Looks like this was an RSS issue - thanks for pointing it out, should be fixed now

Comment: @Alex Miller The RSS Feed seems to be completely broken now :/ http://dl.dropbox.com/u/357576/2011-05-17%2012.29.11%20am.png

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately iTunes caches RSS feeds so problems like this are held over and last longer.  If you hit the RSS directly (http://blog.stackexchange.com/feed/podcast) you can see that its working now.  iTunes should be fixed be later tonight

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Comment: +1 - The only issue is that the JPEG compression on Jeff's picture is a little excessive.

Comment: That will do. But Jeffs diabolical grin is scary.

Comment: @Henrik really? I picked it because I thought it's the most sweetly smiling image there is of him. Well, such is the way interpretations differ!

Comment: Indeed :) Kölsche Grüße!

Comment: @Henrik hehe, wußte ich gar nicht. Grüße zurück!

Comment: @HenrikP.Hessel, Pekka: Please refrain from using foreign languages here. Hochdeutsch ist Pflicht, kommt mir nicht mit diesem Kölsch-Krams.